# Группировка по месяцам

Tags: mysql

Есть обычная таблица страниц только create_date тип INT(15) и сохраняются дата значения php time().

```
|id|title|text|create_date
```

Как можно при таком положении выбрать группированные данные по месяцам?

Нужно получить результат в таком виде:

```
[
[0]=>[здесь массив за январь],
[1]=>[здесь массив за февраль],
[2]=>[здесь массив за Март],
...
]
```

Comment: Уточните вопрос, что вы пробовали, что не получается?

Comment: @KromStern, признаюсь мозг ленится.
    `SELECT * FROM page GROUP BY MONTH(`create_date`)`

Но не работает это.

Comment: А дальше, вам по сути нужен метод перевода вашей даты в обычную дату?

Comment: Приведите пример значения, которое хранится в create_date

Comment: @Aries, Например вот 1442301267

Comment: @KromStern, без разницы, мне лиж бы сгруппировать по месяцам, остальное мало важно

Comment: функция `time()` возвращает строку, а вы пишете, что тип данных — `int`. нет ли здесь противоречия? // p.s. число 1442301267 весьма напоиминает unix timestamp.

Comment: @bemulima разница в вопросе, или вы спрашиваете как группировать, или как перевести время. Согласитесь, это 2 разных ответа, и ответ на 1й вам ничем не поможет. Учитесь формулировать свои пожелания точнее )

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, с чего ли строка, time() же возвращает значения int же

Comment: @KromStern, смотря кому формулировать)

Comment: @bemulima, в [документации написано: string](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, )))  я имел ввиду в php

Answer (score 3):

Т.е. если значение хранится в UnixTime, то просто преобразуем его в дату и дальше используем функцию `Month`.

```
select Month(FROM_UNIXTIME(create_date)), count(*)
FROM page 
GROUP BY Month(FROM_UNIXTIME(create_date))
```

PS в целом, это решит проблему, но является плохим примером SQL запроса с точки зрения производительности, т.е. вызов функций при группировке (как и в условиях) нежелателен при больших объемах данных.

Comment: Спасибо @Aies сейчас буду колдовать.

Comment: "т.е. вызов функций при группировке (как и в условиях) нежелателен" - неужели он не поймёт, что это то же значение, что и в выбираемом столбце?

Comment: @Qwertiy дело не в том поймет или не поймет что это одно и то же значение, а в том, что для корректной работы SQL оптимизатора ему нужны значения из таблицы, а не результаты вызова функций, иначе об индексах можно сразу забыть. Поэтому лично по своему опыту могу сказать, что при подобных случаях, если таблица имеет несколько миллионов или десятков миллионов записей, и к ней идет частое обращение, то приходится заниматься некоторой денормализацией базы и вводом избыточных данных, вроде отдельного столбца "месяц", помимо полной даты.